# Which Ubuntu distribution should I use for my old desktop?

Tags: system-requirements

I have an old computer which has 512MB RAM and 128MB Graphic card. It has windows 95 currently, it loads fine but it has some issues with Internet connection and pendrive.
I am tired of solving problems.

I booted live CD of Ubuntu 10.10. It loads slow and some display problems. But it resolved my internet problem and pendrive. So I want install Ubuntu which is equivalent to windows 95 in boot, application load, graphics level. Can anyone suggest Ubuntu version? What about Xubuntu?

Comment: Sorry my system has 320 MB RAM

Answer (score 7):

I would say use Lubuntu. It will perform better on your system specs.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: I ran Lubuntu for a while on a laptop with 256Mb RAM, which it did reasonably happily. When the price of RAM dropped, I popped in a 1Gb bar, and it was very happy. I also used it on an old desktop for a while which had sufficient RAM to run vanilla Ubuntu, but it was difficult to configure. Lubuntu ran effortlessly, faultlessly, no tweaking from me required. I now run Linux Mint Xfce on the laptop, and it seems about equally snappy as Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try XUBUNTU which uses lightweight XFCE desktop enviroment and is based on UBUNTU.

Comment: Particularly unless you can add more RAM.

Comment: Hey I am trying to install xubuntu and getting some graphics not initialized error.

Comment: Try using Lubuntu 10.04 LTS, or best alternative is Puppy Linux.

Comment: What would be the minimum graphics and RAM required for Lubuntu. I am asking this because I am trying to install Xubuntu it works fine in my laptop. But it loads too slow(as ubutntu 10.10) in my old desktop. I have downloaded lubuntu 12.10. can i install it? or u want me to download lubuntu 10.04

Comment: @clickit - I would use lubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 and not 10.04

Comment: @clickit- Give a try to Puppy Linux

Comment: @laurent what your system configuration? I installed xubuntu which has 320MB RAM and i don't know abt graphic card, the display is blur and load time is also very high. Can you suggest me to try lubuntu 12.10?

Comment: @clickit, yes you can try lubuntu 12.10 which is a based on latest ubuntu 12.10 version,go for it.

Comment: @KashmirHackers What would you think about alternate installer of lubuntu

Comment: @clickit [Lubuntu system requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#System_Requirements)

Comment: @all I tried Lubuntu 12.10 no change in performance. I don't think Lubuntu is as much light weight as windows 98. My system runs windows 98 with optimal performace. Anyone suggest other version of x or l ubuntu which is equivalent to windows 95. And one more thing is when i boot cd of x or l ubuntu it is showing graphics initialization failed before boot and when booted display so worst that I can't see things only. Please help I am struggling a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have ubuntu minimal installation . then install basic gui.

if you like to have cli then it needs only 70-100MB .